# why does my code work in the console but never inline

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been hacking a little WordPress plug-in here, to make it work as I like, and I have this line to which I would like to add a class.

here is the js, that works in console, but never works inline on the page or anywhere else:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    const perf = document.querySelector('[aria-label="Europe marker"]');
    $(perf).addClass("POP");
    console.log("custom variable perf is:", perf); /// 
    $('.POP').click(function() {
      // 
      var x = $(".mapplic-layer-down");
      var y = $(".mapplic-visible");
      // 
      console.log($(x).attr("data-floor")); // print x
      console.log($(y).attr("data-floor")); // print y
      // switch classes 
      $(x).removeClass("mapplic-layer-down, mapplic-hidden");
      $(x).addClass("mapplic-visible");

      $(y).removeClass("mapplic-visible");
      $(y).addClass("mapplic-layer-down, mapplic-hidden");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="mapplic-pin pin-pulse pin-label" aria-label="Europe marker" style="top: 24.65%; left: 48.7%; background-color: rgb(0, 84, 135); border-color: rgb(0, 84, 135); transition: transform 0s ease 0s; transform: scale(3);" data-location="1972"><span><span>9</span></span></a>
```

Comment: You don't need to use both `DOMContentLoaded` and `jQuery(function()...)`.

Comment: Use `$([aria-label="Europe marker"]')` if you're using jquery. No need for `document.querySelector`

Comment: When you say inline; where do you mean?

Comment: When you have multiple classes in `addClass()` and `removeClass()` they should be separated by spaces, not commas.

Comment: There are multiple calls to `addClass()` in the code. Which ones are not working as expected?

Comment: If you use `$(selector)` to set a variable, you don't need to wrap the variable in `$()` again. So `$(x).addClass()` can be `x.addClass()`

Comment: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'` won't fire if the DOMContent has already loaded - but jquery doc.ready will (see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/657vpdsk/)), so if you did put this in the console after the page loaded, it wouldn't do anything

Comment: Not sure how that code would work in the console.